# Why does python selects the variable type as string

Tags: string, class, input, types, integer

When I write something like this

```
a = input("Please enter the number: ")
Please enter the number: 12
type(a)
<class 'str'>
```

It always thinks as like its a string even tho its a number. Is there any solution to make python choose the variable type correct? What I am searching for is something like this

```
a = input("Please enter the number: ")
Please enter the number: 12.5
type(a)
<class 'float'>
```

Is there any command to do this? Except from "eval", to pick the variable type correctly, when its a number as a integer, when it has decimal place as a float, when its bunch of letters its a string. Is there any command to do something like this?

Comment: Do you need  to make sure it is an integer or would you be happy with it being cast as a float?

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the input to an **integer**

```
a = int(input("Please enter the number: "))
```

Comment: Ok - the problem I have is the OP has not confirmed if he wants to have int/float identified as different.